# How to display billing phone on my account page in woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

How can I display the users woocommerce billing phone number on the my account page ([woocommerce_my_account]) and also be able to edit on the edit-address/shipping/ page? I'm editing the my-address.php file.

```
        <address>
        <?php
            $address = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_address_formatted_address', array(
                'first_name'  => get_user_meta( $customer_id, $name . '_first_name', true ),
                'last_name'   => get_user_meta( $customer_id, $name . '_last_name', true ),
                'company'     => get_user_meta( $customer_id, $name . '_company', true ),
                'address_1'   => get_user_meta( $customer_id, $name . '_address_1', true ),
                'address_2'   => get_user_meta( $customer_id, $name . '_address_2', true ),
                'city'        => get_user_meta( $customer_id, $name . '_city', true ),
                'state'       => get_user_meta( $customer_id, $name . '_state', true ),
                'postcode'    => get_user_meta( $customer_id, $name . '_postcode', true ),
                'billing_phone'    => get_user_meta( $customer_id, $name . '_billing_phone', true ),
                'country'     => get_user_meta( $customer_id, $name . '_country', true )
            ), $customer_id, $name );

            $formatted_address = WC()->countries->get_formatted_address( $address );

            if ( ! $formatted_address )
                _e( 'You have not set up this type of address yet.', 'mk_framework' );
            else
                echo $formatted_address;
        ?>

    </address>
```

Comment: Show us what you have done so far

Comment: @Shanoop Posted the code im working with. I added "billing_phone" but it doesn't display on the my account page.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just show a phone number in woocommerce. In order to do it you must add the fields to the registration by using the actions in this [page](https://support.woothemes.com/hc/en-us/articles/203182373-How-to-add-custom-fields-in-user-registration-on-the-My-Account-page).

Then on your account page add the following wherever you want to display the phone number.

*'phone'   => get_user_meta( $customer_id, $name . '_phone', true ),*

Answer (score 0):

When you use it like this it will pull up the actual fields:

```
'billing_phone' => get_user_meta( $customer_id, $name . '_phone', true ),
'billing_email' => get_user_meta( $customer_id, $name . '_email', true )
```